# Get the first sentence from string using php

Tags: php, string

I have some content stored in a variable and it looks like"

```
$content = "This is a test content and the content of the url is http://www.test.com. The is a second sentence.";
```

Now my code is

```
$pos = strpos($content, '.');
$firstsentence = substr($content, 0, $pos);
```

The above code doesn't work as the string already contains a url having dots.

How can I get the first sentence considering the fact that a string contains a hyperlink?

Comment: If you want this to work anything close to reliable in all cases, you'll need to use natural language processing, which analyses and understands grammar. Doing it based on a regular expression or simply the first `.` or something similar will virtually always lead to false positives.

Comment: You going to have to cover a *lot* of edge cases. What about the string, “Mr. Doe went to the market.” What about, “He was 1.8 metres in height.” So many scenarios to consider where a period doesn’t equate the end of a sentence. You may as well just truncate to a specific character limit.

Comment: hmm...that's quite possible. @Martin

Comment: Or use `\n` to delimit your lines, that's what it's meant for.

Comment: @Loïc Not really. Newline characters are meant for, well, new lines. Not sentence ends.

Comment: I should haven't posted this question.. :p

Answer (score 1):

Please share other scenarios of text. This works fine for your example:

```
$sentences = 'This is a test content and the content of the url is http://www.test.com. The is a second sentence.';

preg_match('/(http|https):(.*?)com/', $sentences, $match);

$sentences = preg_replace('/(http|https):(.*?)com/', '', $sentences);

$pos = strpos($sentences, '.');
$pos .= -1;

$firstsentence = substr($sentences, 0, $pos) .$match[0].'.';
//This is a test content and the content of the url is http://www.test.com.
```

Answer (score -1):

In general, I think you're going to also have to look for `<sentence-end-punct>"<whitespace>`, `"<sentence-end-punct><whitespace>`, and `<sentence-end-punct><whitespace>` (where <whitespace> includes the end of a line). Is this very general English text, not especially under your control, or is the grammar very limited? For non-English text, there can be additional rules, such as putting spaces between punctuation and quotes.

Add: What are you trying to accomplish here? Do you really need to pull apart text into individual sentences, or are you just trying to create a "teaser". In the latter case, just cut off the text at a complete word before some number of characters, and add an ellipsis (...).

Comment: This would fail for salutations like ‘Mr. Doe’.